# Checking if widget has title not working

Tags: widgets

Here's my function which is not working:

```
function ts_dynamic_sidebar_params($params) {
    global $wp_registered_widgets;
    $settings_getter = $wp_registered_widgets[ $params[0]['widget_id'] ]['callback'][0];
    $settings = $settings_getter->get_settings();
    $settings = $settings[ $params[1]['number'] ];

    if ( isset($settings['title']) ) {
        $params[0]['before_widget'] = '<div class="widget">Widget Has Title';
    }

    return $params;
}
add_filter('dynamic_sidebar_params', 'ts_dynamic_sidebar_params');
```

Anyone knows why `if ( isset($settings['title']) )` not working as expected here?

Comment: can you describe what is working differently from what you expect?

Comment: `isset($settings['title'])` is always true, regardless of the widget has title or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is memory and I can't test right now, but I believe the title is always set. Use `!empty( $settings['title'] )` instead and I think you will get the results you expect.

Comment: !empty( $settings['title'] ) always return true also.

Comment: Then the title is set and has content.

Comment: Nope. I have some widgets with no title at all but still return true for `isset($settings['title'])` or `!empty( $settings['title'] )`

Comment: `var_dump` the title right before your conditional. What is it? Code doesn't misbehave "just because". Usually, the programmer is missing something. `empty` should work for " not set" and empty string/array". Saying that it us giving the wrong answer is a bit like trying to argue with math.

Comment: This is what I get with `var_daump`: `["title"]=> string(0) ""` for all widgets, whether they have title or not.

Comment: Ok. It seems that the problem is that some widgets automatically add titles, such as 'Newest posts' widget. So the `isset($settings['title'])` won't work for it unless you add your custom title to the widget. Is there still any clue to check if a widget has a title, whether inserted or automatically generated?

Comment: Maybe. I'll have to look into it later.

Comment: This is what 'recent posts' widget is using: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/default-widgets.php#L815